# Unable to initiate a boiler plate fast api code

Tags: python, fastapi

I come from Javascript land so this bit confusing to me.

I am trying to use this as a boiler plate code for a project: https://github.com/anthonycepeda/fastapi-sqlmodel

This is there for quick start

```
### Quickstart
 1.  <b>Start the App</b>:
 2. Using Python:
    `pipenv run python asgi.py`

 3. sing Docker:
    `docker build -t sqlmodel-api:latest . && docker run -p 8080:8080 sqlmodel-api:latest`

 4. <b>Use Openapi at</b>: `http://localhost:8080/#/`
```

but there wasn't anything mention for installation.

So, to start with I did `pip install` and `pipenv shell` from here.

and then proceeded to run following command

`pipenv run python asgi.py`

This throws following error

```
  File "/Users/userB/Desktop/fastapi-sql-blog/asgi.py", line 3, in <module>
    from api.app import create_app
  File "/Users/userB/Desktop/fastapi-sql-blog/api/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from api.config import settings
  File "/Users/userB/Desktop/fastapi-sql-blog/api/config.py", line 21, in <module>
    settings = Settings()
  File "/Users/userB/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-sql-blog-a9YFiCXV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/env_settings.py", line 36, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/userB/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-sql-blog-a9YFiCXV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 406, in __init__
    raise validation_error
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Settings
ENV
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
VERSION
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The error log explains the problem

```
ENV
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
VERSION
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

These two fields are mandatory when creating an instance of the class `Settings`. The exception is triggered on line `settings = Settings()` of "/Users/userB/Desktop/fastapi-sql-blog/api/config.py", line 21

Change therefore the instantation of the `Settings` class or add some default values